# Python Pandas Series gives NaN data when passing a dict with large index values

Tags: dictionary, python-2.7, pandas, series

I am trying to build a Pandas series by passing it a dictionary containing index and data pairs. While doing so I noticed an interesting quirk. If the index of the data pair is a very large integer the data will show up as NaN. This is fixed by reducing the size of the index values, or creating the Series using two lists instead of a single dict. I have large index values because I am using time-stamps in microseconds-since-1970 format. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

test_series_time = [1357230060000000, 1357230180000000, 1357230300000000]
test_series_value = [1, 2, 3]
series = pd.Series(test_series_value, test_series_time, name="this works")

test_series_dict = {1357230060000000: 1, 1357230180000000: 2, 1357230300000000: 3}
series2 = pd.Series(test_series_dict, name="this doesn't")

test_series_dict_smaller_index = {1357230060: 1, 1357230180: 2, 1357230300: 3}
series3 = pd.Series(test_series_dict_smaller_index, name="this does")

print series
print series2
print series3
```

and the output:

```
1357230060000000    1
1357230180000000    2
1357230300000000    3
Name: this works

1357230060000000   NaN
1357230180000000   NaN
1357230300000000   NaN
Name: this doesn't

1357230060    1
1357230180    2
1357230300    3
Name: this does
```

So what's up with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you are on 32-bit; on 64-bit this works fine. In 0.10.1, the default of creation via dicts is to use the default numpy integer creation, which is system dependent (e.g. int32 on 32-bit, and int64 on 64-bit). You are overflowing the dtype, which results in unpredictable behavior.

In 0.11 (coming out this week!), this will work as it will default to creating int64s regardless of the system.

```
In [12]: np.iinfo(np.int32).max
Out[12]: 2147483647

In [13]: np.iinfo(np.int64).max
Out[13]: 9223372036854775807
```

Convert your microseconds to Timestamps (multiply by 1000 to put in nanoseconds which is what Timestamp accepts as an integer input, then you are good to go

```
In [5]: pd.Series(test_series_value, 
        [ pd.Timestamp(k*1000) for k in test_series_time ])
Out[5]: 
2013-01-03 16:21:00    1
2013-01-03 16:23:00    2
2013-01-03 16:25:00    3
```

Comment: That makes sense, I am running the 32 bit version, thanks for the good explanation! Looking forward to the new release.